# Rep value on the new flair is not updated

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, flair

There is an update issue with the new flairs. Yesterday I replaced all my flair snippets with the new ones, but the rep value on the "default theme" has not been updated. Here is a screeny:

[image]

The other themes show the correct value whereas the default one does not.

Comment: Presumably the images are cached for some amount of time... not sure what that time *is*, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's cached for 24 hours minimum. If you don't see it changing within 48-96 hours let us know.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Jeff. It's been updated after 24 hours.

Comment: I think that this should be stated on the flair pages.

Comment: Agreed. It should be stated. I noticed mine hasn't been updating right away as well.