# How often is the flair image refreshed?

Tags: support

If I go to Stackoverflow.com it says I have 6126 rep, but the image [says 6081](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/244296.png). How often is the image refreshed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jeff said [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65889/rep-value-on-the-new-flair-is-not-updated/65890#65890):

> It's cached for 24 hours minimum